# Get File Extension for special cases like tar.gz

Tags: java, file, utility-method

I need to extract extensions from file names.

I know this can be done for single extensions like `.gz` or `.tar` by using `filePath.lastIndexOf('.')` or using utility methods like `FilenameUtils.getExtension(filePath)` from Apache commons-io.

*But*, what if I have a file with an extension like `.tar.gz`? How can I manage files with extensions that contain `.` characters?

Comment: Actually, the extension is not `.tar.gz`. The extension - by definition - is `.gz`. The `.tar` part is only for informational purposes. If the file ended with `.test.zip` you would consider the extension `.zip`, wouldn't you?

Comment: and `commons-io-2.4.jar` in this case what you would expect ?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar It is still reasonable to handle *.tar.gz reasonable, just like *.tgz, mind you.

Comment: oh it's true I haven't realized that @ThorstenDittmar. So .tar.gz and .gz both have the same File properties (e.g. icon) in this case?

Comment: If you don't want to use commons-io, there is a similar method in Guava; `Files.getFileExtension(filePath)` - but it uses the same `lastIndexOf('.')` technique.

Comment: Why has this been closed? The question is reasonable, and *demonstrate[s] a minimal understanding of the problem* as far as I can see. Certainly, there was enough information for me to provide an answer, which was then accepted. I have edited the question slightly to clarify this, and the edit has been accepted.

Comment: @vels4j In that case `commons-io-2.4.jar` has the extension `jar`. For other extensions, the mappings should look like this: `commons-io-2.4.tar` = `tar`, `commons-io-2.4.tar.bz2` = `tar.bz2`, `commons-io-2.4.tgz.shar` = `tgz.shar`, `commons-io-2.4.tgz` = `tgz`, `commons-io-2.4.jar.md5` = `md5`. Note the last one, this is an MD5 signature of the Jar file, so the extension is `md5` not `jar.md5`.

Comment: @grkvlt I knew, but what if you get an unknown type. That is how this question is closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know what extensions are important, you can simply check for them explicitly. You would have a collection of known extensions, like this:

```
List<String> EXTS = Arrays.asList("tar.gz", "tgz", "gz", "zip");
```

You could get the (first) longest matching extension like this:

```
String getExtension(String fileName) {
  String found = null;
  for (String ext : EXTS) {
    if (fileName.endsWith("." + ext)) {
      if (found == null || found.length() < ext.length()) {
        found = ext;
      }
    }
  }
  return found;
}
```

So calling `getExtension("file.tar.gz")` would return `"tar.gz"`.

If you have mixed-case names, perhaps try changing the check to `filename.toLowerCase().endsWith("." + ext)` inside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

A file can just have one extension!

If you have a file `test.tar.gz`,

- `.gz` is the extension and
- `test.tar` is the Basename!

`.tar` in this case is part of the basename, not the part of the extension!

If you like to have a file encoded as `tar` and `gz` you should call it `.tgz`. To use a `.tar.gz` is bad practice, if you need to handle thesse files you should make a workaround like rename the file to `test.tgz`.

Comment: Beg to differ: the "extension" is whatever some application defines it to be. From a OS point of view there is no such thing as an "extension".

Comment: A OS pov, hm ... its maybe more save to say from FS pov.

Comment: this is not helping if you are renaming your file to uuid + extension, you will get from `foo.tar.gz` to `61822326-ef4d-49f4-971d-b20269c72db9.gz`  ...

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple way. Use `substring` to get filename only and `indexOf` instead of `lastIndexOf` to get first '.' and extension after it

Comment: So what would your program consider the extension if I gave you a file `program.logs.tar.gz`?

Comment: Agree, this won't work for files with things like version numbers embedded in them.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the filename part of the path, split on `.` and take the final 0, 1, or 2 elements in the array as the extension.

Of course if `.tar.*` (gz, bz2, etc.) is your only edge case it may be pragmatic to just build a solution that filters filenames for .tar. and use that as the point at which to extract the extension (to include the .tar portion).